# Using Caliburn.Micro.Contrib Generic DialogBox

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro, dialog

I'm pretty new to C# programming. I started developing a WPF application using the MVVM pattern and Caliburn.Micro framework. I've also added Caliburn.Micro.Contrib library as it contains some useful dialog boxes.

I tried using it in my project, but I can't get it to work. 
When I click on the button that should display the dialog box, I have an empty window saying that the view cannot be found:  (Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer])

I have setup the Caliburn.Micro bootstrap to embed the CM Contrib assembly:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    return base.SelectAssemblies().Concat(new Assembly[] { typeof(ResultExtensions).Assembly       }); 
}
```

And the execute method in my view-model class:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> DeleteItem()
    {
        var question = new Question("The Subject","The Message", Answer.Yes, Answer.No);

        yield return question.AsResult().CancelOnResponse(Answer.No);

    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

*Edit*:

Here the full bootstrap

```
 public class NInjectBootstrapper<TRootModel> : Bootstrapper<TRootModel>
{
    protected IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The base type required for a view model
    /// </summary>
    public Type ViewModelBaseType { get; set; }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        //  allow base classes to change bootstrapper settings
        ConfigureBootstrapper();

        var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
        var loadedPaths = loadedAssemblies.Select(a => a.Location).ToArray();

        var referencedPaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll");
        var toLoad = referencedPaths.Where(r =>r.Contains("TxS.") && !loadedPaths.Contains(r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        toLoad.ForEach(path => loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path))));


        Bootstrapper.With.Ninject().Start();   

        Kernel = Bootstrapper.Container as IKernel;


        //ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs", "TxSGUI.Views");
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(System.Type service, string key)
    {
        object instance;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            instance = Kernel.TryGet(service);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = Kernel.TryGet(service, key); 
        }

        if(instance == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}", key ?? service.Name));


        return instance; 
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(System.Type service)
    {
        return Kernel.GetAll(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        Kernel.Inject(instance);
    }

    protected virtual void ConfigureBootstrapper()
    {   
        //  the default view model base type
        ViewModelBaseType = typeof(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged);
    }


    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        return base.SelectAssemblies().Concat(new Assembly[] { typeof(ResultExtensions).Assembly });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override to include your own Autofac configuration after the framework has finished its configuration, but 
    /// before the container is created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The Autofac configuration builder.</param>
    protected virtual void ConfigureContainer(IKernel builder)
    {
    }
}
```

and the NInject module (to bind views and other things)

```
  public class TxSGuiModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // Bind Window Manager
        Kernel.Bind<IWindowManager>().To<WindowManager>().InSingletonScope();

        // Bind Event Aggregator
        Kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();

        // Bind Main View
        Kernel.Bind<TxSMainViewModel>().To<TxSMainViewModel>().InSingletonScope().Named(typeof(TxSMainViewModel).Name);

        // Bind Views
        Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IShell>()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel") && t.Namespace.StartsWith("TxSGUI"))
            .BindSelection((a, c) =>
            {
                IList<Type> list = new List<Type>();
                list.Add(typeof(IShell));
                list.Add(a);

                return list;
            })
            .Configure(b => b.InTransientScope()));

        // Bind Actions
        Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IAction>().BindAllInterfaces().Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
    }
}
```

After activated the Caliburn Log, here what I have:

```
07/31/2013 14:46:21 - INFO - [Coroutine] - Executing coroutine.  
07/31/2013 14:46:21 - WARN - [ViewLocator] - View not found. Searched: Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Dialog.Question.  
07/31/2013 14:46:21 - INFO - [ViewModelBinder] - Binding System.Windows.Window: Cannot find view for Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer]. and Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer].  
07/31/2013 14:46:21 - INFO - [Action] - Setting DC of System.Windows.Window: Cannot find view for Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer]. to Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer].  
07/31/2013 14:46:21 - INFO - [Action] - Attaching message handler Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer] to System.Windows.Window: Cannot find view for Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer]..  
07/31/2013 14:46:21 - INFO - [ViewModelBinder] - Attaching System.Windows.Window: Cannot find view for Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer]. to Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.DialogViewModel`1[Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Answer].
```

Comment: Can you show your complete bootstrapper please ?

Comment: I have edited my post, however I don't think there is something fancy about it.

Comment: Well everything looks good in your bootstrapper so i can't tell you what might be wrong, but i could suggest to let Caliburn.Micro log everything it is doing by using a DebugLogger like the one in [**this article**](http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/08/how-to-do-logging-with-caliburn-micro/) then you will see why it is failing to locate that view and from there you could go on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have activated it, and here what I have in the log:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the source code again and found the source of the problem. It lies in the `DialogResult` type and specifically in the `Execute` method of the `IResult` which passes a context parameter to the `WindowManager.ShowDialog()` which is causing the problem.

I have looked a bit further and found an article written by the library author about dialogs and some one in the comments had the same problem as yours and the suggested solution was to call the following line of code in the `Configure()` method of your bootstrapper:

```
FrameworkExtensions.ViewLocator.EnableContextFallback();
```

Here is a link to the [Comment](http://kmees.github.io/blog/2011/06/16/mvvm-dialogs-with-caliburn-dot-micro/#comment-543976683) and here is the [article](http://kmees.github.io/blog/2011/06/16/mvvm-dialogs-with-caliburn-dot-micro).

If this doesn't work I got nothing else to say, I did all I can.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I've just try that (I have already try it), but no luck, i got the same error, in fact, CM try to find the exact same view, and when you change the type de DialogType, it try to find the corresponding view.

Comment: @Tarteens What do you mean by "and when you change the type de DialogType, it try to find the corresponding view", can you explain further please ?

Comment: if I set DialogType.Question, in the log I have:View not found. Searched: Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Dialog.Question.
and if I set DialogType.Information, in the log I have: View not found. Searched: Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Dialogs.Dialog.Information

Comment: @Tarteens I have completely changed my answer, please check edit.

Comment: thanks for your help, the EnableContextFallback did the trick.